# Accidentally broke of an SMD part of my iPhone 5's logic board (DZ17)

Tags: iphone, hardware, logicboard

Well, sh**...

It's the tiny part at the very very top right of the logic board (camera facing away, so as it lays in your iPhone when you open it)
I don't know what to do now.

What kind of part is it, what does it do?
Is it redundant / can I bridge it or what shall I do now?
It flipped away and since it's so tiny it's hopeless to look for it.

Speedy help is much appreciated to keep the time of having my iPhone openly laying around as little as possible and to, well, have my iPhone back. :)

Comment: Not sure whether I may link the schematics here, but they are easy to find with Google. (first page of schematics, right image, very top right - there's the part)

Comment: Not sure if anyone will be able to help here, but at a minimum, it would be helpful if you place the image along with any other useful information within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's an ESD protection component, but one that isn't able to take a whole lot anyways, so operation without it can be considered reasonable, especially when considering the amount of work that would go into ordering a replacement and soldering it on the board.
Source: Chat over at EEV Blog. (I forgot the username, otherwise I'd love to give proper credits!)